# Normal JSON to GraphSON format

Tags: javascript, json, gremlin, gremlin-server, graphson

I have two questions:

1. Where I can actually find the basic format for a GraphSON file, that is guaranteed to be successfully loaded by the gremlin console? I'm trying to convert a JSON (with about 10-20 fields) to another file that can be queried by gremlin but I can't actually find any relevant information about the fields reserved by the graphson format or how I should handle the IDs etc. I exported the modern graph they provide and it's not even a valid JSON (Multiple JSON root elements), but a list of JSONs [1] I also saw fields like outE, inE...are these fields something I manually have to create?
2. If I am able to create the JSON, where do I tell the server to load it as the base graph when I start it? In the config file or in the script?

Thanks!
Adrian

[1] https://pastebin.com/drwXhg5k

```
{"id":1,"label":"person","outE":{"created":[{"id":9,"inV":3,"properties":{"weight":0.4}}],"knows":[{"id":7,"inV":2,"properties":{"weight":0.5}},{"id":8,"inV":4,"properties":{"weight":1.0}}]},"properties":{"name":[{"id":0,"value":"marko"}],"age":[{"id":1,"value":29}]}}
{"id":2,"label":"person","inE":{"knows":[{"id":7,"outV":1,"properties":{"weight":0.5}}]},"properties":{"name":[{"id":2,"value":"vadas"}],"age":[{"id":3,"value":27}]}}
{"id":3,"label":"software","inE":{"created":[{"id":9,"outV":1,"properties":{"weight":0.4}},{"id":11,"outV":4,"properties":{"weight":0.4}},{"id":12,"outV":6,"properties":{"weight":0.2}}]},"properties":{"name":[{"id":4,"value":"lop"}],"lang":[{"id":5,"value":"java"}]}}
{"id":4,"label":"person","inE":{"knows":[{"id":8,"outV":1,"properties":{"weight":1.0}}]},"outE":{"created":[{"id":10,"inV":5,"properties":{"weight":1.0}},{"id":11,"inV":3,"properties":{"weight":0.4}}]},"properties":{"name":[{"id":6,"value":"josh"}],"age":[{"id":7,"value":32}]}}
{"id":5,"label":"software","inE":{"created":[{"id":10,"outV":4,"properties":{"weight":1.0}}]},"properties":{"name":[{"id":8,"value":"ripple"}],"lang":[{"id":9,"value":"java"}]}}
{"id":6,"label":"person","outE":{"created":[{"id":12,"inV":3,"properties":{"weight":0.2}}]},"properties":{"name":[{"id":10,"value":"peter"}],"age":[{"id":11,"value":35}]}}
```

Comment: Could you please supply the original json file you would like to convert? Even if latet I might have a different approach available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Where I can actually find the basic format for a GraphSON file, that is guaranteed to be successfully loaded by the gremlin console?

There are multiple versions of GraphSON at this point. You can get a reference in the Apache TinkerPop [IO Documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/dev/io/). When you write, "successfully loaded by the gremlin console" I assume that you mean with the `GraphSONReader` methods described [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#graphson-reader-writer). Of so, then the format you show above is one form you can use. It is not valid JSON as you can see, though you can build the reader/writer with the `wrapAdjacencyList` option set to `true` and it will produce valid JSON. Here is an example:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern();
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> writer =  graph.io(IoCore.graphson()).writer().wrapAdjacencyList(true).create()
==>org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONWriter@24a298a6
gremlin> os = new FileOutputStream('wrapped-adjacency-list.json')
==>java.io.FileOutputStream@6d3c232f
gremlin> writer.writeGraph(os, graph)
gremlin> os.close()
gremlin> newGraph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> ins = new FileInputStream('wrapped-adjacency-list.json')
==>java.io.FileInputStream@7435a578
gremlin> reader = graph.io(IoCore.graphson()).reader().unwrapAdjacencyList(true).create()
==>org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONReader@63da207f
gremlin> reader.readGraph(ins, newGraph)
gremlin> newGraph
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
```

The reason you do not get valid JSON by default is because the standard format for a GraphSON file needs to be splittable for Hadoop and other distributed processing engines. Therefore it produces one line per vertex - a `StarGraph` format.

> If I am able to create the JSON, where do I tell the server to load it as the base graph when I start it? In the config file or in the script?

A script would work. as would the `gremlin.tinkergraph.graphLocation` and `gremlin.tinkergraph.graphFormat` [configuration options](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_configuration_3) on TinkerGraph.

Ultimately though, if you have existing JSON and you aren't loading tens of millions of graph elements, it is probably easiest to just parse it and use standard `g.addV()` and `g.addE()` methods to build the graph:

```
gremlin> import groovy.json.*
==>org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.*,...
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
==>groovy.json.JsonSlurper@53e3a87a
gremlin> object = jsonSlurper.parseText('[{ "name": "John Doe" }, { "name" : "Jane Doe" }]')
==>[name:John Doe]
==>[name:Jane Doe]
gremlin> object.each {g.addV('name',it.name).iterate() }
==>[name:John Doe]
==>[name:Jane Doe]
gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>[name:[John Doe]]
==>[name:[Jane Doe]]
```

Trying to convert that to GraphSON is overly complicated compared to the approach above.

Comment: What should I use to easily convert a normal JSON to a GraphJSON that can be loaded and used later? (I use TinkerPop, yes).
By the way, what is "wrapAdjacencyList" option and where to I set it? I am working in the console right now and later I'll work with javascript.

Comment: See the builders in the javadocs: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/io/graphson/package-summary.html for the `wrapAdjacencyList` option`. not sure if that answers all of your question 
 - I don't know what you mean by "easily convert normal JSON to a GraphJSON".

Comment: But how do you actually use wrapAdjacencyList in the console? I tried with 
"graph.io(IoCore.graphson()).wrapAdjacencyList("true").writeGraph("tinkerpop-modern.json")" but I receive the following error: No signature of method: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONIo.wrapAdjacencyList() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [true]

Comment: I still find it difficult to create a new graph from an existing JSON (where each field must be a vertex and between each of them must be an edge => for n fields => n vertices => n * (n + 1) / 2 edges). But...the outE and inE are kind of hard to make, in my oppinion. Using the wrapAdjacencyList property does not make this any easier, because it's exactly the other way around. There isn't a parser that does this, right?

Comment: By the way, if I actually manage to create a graph with the first method, if I use gremlin.tinkergraph.graphLocation and gremlin.tinkergraph.graphFormat in the config file, I will be able to use it right away, right? The property of graphLocation will be the path to the JSON I just generated and it will know to automatically load and parse it.

Comment: " it is probably easiest to just parse it and use standard g.addV() and g.addE() methods to build the graph"
Yes, but I actually have to do this from javascript, I won't have the access to a console. I will have a database that can be queried and that will return a JSON. I want to create a graph from that JSON on demand (I will spawn another gremlin server each time). 

I actually want to start the server with an existing graph, constructed from a JSON I previously downloaded and transformed in a GraphSON fromat. Using JavaScript...I can't really achieve this in another way.

Comment: Also, if there is an easier method to communicate, that will be awesome. I see that you know a lot of things about this and it will be faster on a chat or by email, I think.

Comment: the console was just to provide example code. you can do that from a gremlin server init script easy enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148444/discussion-between-adi-and-stephen-mallette).